# Possible to peer 2 azure vnets (A -- B) where one of the vnets has already an existing peer with a vnet (C)that an overlapping cidr range?

Tags: azure, peer, vnet

Any ideas on a workaround on how to peer 2 vnet in azure where one of the vnet has a existing peering with a vnet that has an overlapping cidr range?

Looking at NAT gateways but this seems more for routing traffic from a private out to the internet.
Thanks
Brian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to peer virtual networks with overlapping address space. If you intend to peer these VNets, you need to change the address space in one of that VNets.

VNet peering enables you to seamlessly connect Azure virtual networks. Once peered, the VNets appear as one, for connectivity purposes. If there are overlapping CIDR ranges, the address conflicts.